# How to specify MSbuild output folder?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2009

When I execute delphi 2009 project using MSBuild command line, output always goes to C: drive

```
C:\MyProjects>MSbuild "C:\MyTestProject\Test.dproj" /t:Build /p:OutDir="C:\Output\bin\"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I know the [docs say otherwise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx), but try OutputPath instead of OutDir.

Comment: Yeah OutputPath should be used instead of OutDir, the docs are wrong in this case.

Comment: It's better to use `DCC_ExeOutput` instead of `OutputPath`, because when you have `PostBuildEvents` and you are using `$(OutputPath)`, then `/p:OutputPath="xxx"` will *NOT* be used in `$(OutputPath)`, but if you use `/p:DCC_ExeOutput="xxx"` then it will work correctly.

Comment: I tried this, but MSBuild seems to ignore `OutputPath` when the linker output directory is specified in the project options.

Comment: I found this very amusing: http://www.pseale.com/i-hate-you-outdir-parameter it shows a lot of things that can go wrong with OutDir.

Answer (score 7):

For Delphi projects you need to use DCC_ExeOutput to specify where the EXE should go.

```
C:\MyProjects>MSbuild "C:\MyTestProject\Test.dproj" /t:Build /p:DCC_ExeOutput="C:\Output\bin\"
```

Take a look inside Test.dproj for any other options you might want to specify.

Comment: others properties that affect the Delphi compiler (DCC) can be found here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/what-are-the-msbuild-project-level-properties-for-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373991/what-are-the-msbuild-project-level-properties-for-delphi)