# What are the MSBuild project level properties for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2010

The Delphi documentation for MSBuild says

> /property:name=value sets or overrides
> project-level properties, where name
> is the property name and value is the
> property value. Use a semicolon or a
> comma to separate multiple properties,
> or specify each property separately.
> /p is also acceptable. For example:
>
> /property:WarningLevel=2;OutputDir=bin\Debug

I can't find a list of available properties, here's what I know so far:

- WarningLevel
- OutputDir  (dcc32 -e equivalent)
- Config

I'd like to get a complete list, but I'm most interested in being able to override the Defines (dcc32 -d equivalent).  And if these can be lined up against dcc32 equivalents that'd be icing!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find most of the parameters in the msbuild script *C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Delphi.Targets* when you look at the CoreCompile target.

```
        ExeOutput="$(DCC_ExeOutput)"
        BplOutput="$(DCC_BplOutput)"
        DcuOutput="$(DCC_DcuOutput)"
        DcpOutput="$(DCC_DcpOutput)"
        HppOutput="$(DCC_HppOutput)"
        ObjOutput="$(DCC_ObjOutput)"
        BpiOutput="$(DCC_BpiOutput)"

        DependencyCheckOutputName = "$(DCC_DependencyCheckOutputName)"
        UnitSearchPath="$(UnitSearchPath)"
        ResourcePath="$(ResourcePath)"
        IncludePath="$(IncludePath)"
        ObjPath="$(_ObjectPath)"

        UnitAlias="$(DCC_UnitAlias)"
        ConsoleTarget="$(DCC_ConsoleTarget)"
        Define="$(DCC_Define)"
        FindError="$(DCC_FindError)"
        MapFile="$(DCC_MapFile)"
        Hints="$(DCC_Hints)"
        CBuilderOutput="$(DCC_CBuilderOutput)"
        BaseAddress="$(DCC_BaseAddress)"
        UsePackage="$(_UsePackage)"
        MakeModifiedUnits="$(DCC_MakeModifiedUnits)"
        BuildAllUnits="$(DCC_BuildAllUnits)"
        NameSpace="$(NameSpace)"
        OldDosFileNames="$(DCC_OldDosFileNames)"
        Quiet="$(DCC_Quiet)"
        DebugInfoInExe="$(DCC_DebugInfoInExe)"
        DebugVN="$(DCC_DebugVN)"
        RemoteDebug="$(DCC_RemoteDebug)"
        OutputNeverBuildDcps="$(DCC_OutputNeverBuildDcps)"
        NoConfig="true"
        OutputDRCFile="$(DCC_OutputDRCFile)"
        OutputDependencies="$(DCC_OutputDependencies)"
        OutputXMLDocumentation="$(DCC_OutputXMLDocumentation)"
        DefaultNamespace="$(DCC_DefaultNamespace)"
        Platform="$(DCC_Platform)"
        UnsafeCode="$(DCC_UnsafeCode)"
        Warnings="$(DCC_Warnings)"

        Alignment="$(DCC_Alignment)"
        MinimumEnumSize="$(DCC_MinimumEnumSize)"
        FullBooleanEvaluations="$(DCC_FullBooleanEvaluations)"
        AssertionsAtRuntime="$(DCC_AssertionsAtRuntime)"
        DebugInformation="$(DCC_DebugInformation)"
        ImportedDataReferences="$(DCC_ImportedDataReferences)"
        LongStrings="$(DCC_LongStrings)"
        IOChecking="$(DCC_IOChecking)"
        WriteableConstants="$(DCC_WriteableConstants)"
        LocalDebugSymbols="$(DCC_LocalDebugSymbols)"
        RunTimeTypeInfo="$(DCC_RunTimeTypeInfo)"
        Optimize="$(DCC_Optimize)"
        OpenStringParams="$(DCC_OpenStringParams)"
        IntegerOverflowCheck="$(DCC_IntegerOverflowCheck)"
        RangeChecking="$(DCC_RangeChecking)"
        TypedAtParameter="$(DCC_TypedAtParameter)"
        PentiumSafeDivide="$(DCC_PentiumSafeDivide)"
        StrictVarStrings="$(DCC_StrictVarStrings)"
        GenerateStackFrames="$(DCC_GenerateStackFrames)"
        ExtendedSyntax="$(DCC_ExtendedSyntax)"
        SymbolReferenceInfo="$(DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo)"

        StackSize="$(DCC_StackSize)"
        ImageBase="$(DCC_ImageBase)"
        Description="$(DCC_Description)"

        DelaySign="$(DCC_DelaySign)"
        KeyFile="$(DCC_KeyFile)"
        KeyContainer="$(DCC_KetContainer)"
        CodePage="$(DCC_CodePage)"

        SYMBOL_DEPRECATED="$(DCC_SYMBOL_DEPRECATED)"
        SYMBOL_LIBRARY="$(DCC_SYMBOL_LIBRARY)"
        SYMBOL_PLATFORM="$(DCC_SYMBOL_PLATFORM)"
        SYMBOL_EXPERIMENTAL="$(DCC_SYMBOL_EXPERIMENTAL)"
        UNIT_LIBRARY="$(DCC_UNIT_LIBRARY)"
        UNIT_PLATFORM="$(DCC_UNIT_PLATFORM)"
        UNIT_DEPRECATED="$(DCC_UNIT_DEPRECATED)"
        UNIT_EXPERIMENTAL="$(DCC_UNIT_EXPERIMENTAL)"
        HRESULT_COMPAT="$(DCC_HRESULT_COMPAT)"
        HIDING_MEMBER="$(DCC_HIDING_MEMBER)"
        HIDDEN_VIRTUAL="$(DCC_HIDDEN_VIRTUAL)"
        GARBAGE="$(DCC_GARBAGE)"
        BOUNDS_ERROR="$(DCC_BOUNDS_ERROR)"
        ZERO_NIL_COMPAT="$(DCC_ZERO_NIL_COMPAT)"
        STRING_CONST_TRUNCED="$(DCC_STRING_CONST_TRUNCED)"
        FOR_LOOP_VAR_VARPAR="$(DCC_FOR_LOOP_VAR_VARPAR)"
        TYPED_CONST_VARPAR="$(DCC_TYPED_CONST_VARPAR)"
        ASG_TO_TYPED_CONST="$(DCC_ASG_TO_TYPED_CONST)"
        CASE_LABEL_RANGE="$(DCC_CASE_LABEL_RANGE)"
        FOR_VARIABLE="$(DCC_FOR_VARIABLE)"
        CONSTRUCTING_ABSTRACT="$(DCC_CONSTRUCTING_ABSTRACT)"
        COMPARISON_FALSE="$(DCC_COMPARISON_FALSE)"
        COMPARISON_TRUE="$(DCC_COMPARISON_TRUE)"
        COMPARING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED="$(DCC_COMPARING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED)"
        COMBINING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED="$(DCC_COMBINING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED)"
        UNSUPPORTED_CONSTRUCT="$(DCC_UNSUPPORTED_CONSTRUCT)"
        FILE_OPEN="$(DCC_FILE_OPEN)"
        FILE_OPEN_UNITSRC="$(DCC_FILE_OPEN_UNITSRC)"
        BAD_GLOBAL_SYMBOL="$(DCC_BAD_GLOBAL_SYMBOL)"
        DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR="$(DCC_DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR)"
        INVALID_DIRECTIVE="$(DCC_INVALID_DIRECTIVE)"
        PACKAGE_NO_LINK="$(DCC_PACKAGE_NO_LINK)"
        PACKAGED_THREADVAR="$(DCC_PACKAGED_THREADVAR)"
        IMPLICIT_IMPORT="$(DCC_IMPLICIT_IMPORT)"
        HPPEMIT_IGNORED="$(DCC_HPPEMIT_IGNORED)"
        NO_RETVAL="$(DCC_NO_RETVAL)"
        USE_BEFORE_DEF="$(DCC_USE_BEFORE_DEF)"
        FOR_LOOP_VAR_UNDEF="$(DCC_FOR_LOOP_VAR_UNDEF)"
        UNIT_NAME_MISMATCH="$(DCC_UNIT_NAME_MISMATCH)"
        NO_CFG_FILE_FOUND="$(DCC_NO_CFG_FILE_FOUND)"
        IMPLICIT_VARIANTS="$(DCC_IMPLICIT_VARIANTS)"
        UNICODE_TO_LOCALE="$(DCC_UNICODE_TO_LOCALE)"
        LOCALE_TO_UNICODE="$(DCC_LOCALE_TO_UNICODE)"
        IMAGEBASE_MULTIPLE="$(DCC_IMAGEBASE_MULTIPLE)"
        SUSPICIOUS_TYPECAST="$(DCC_SUSPICIOUS_TYPECAST)"
        PRIVATE_PROPACCESSOR="$(DCC_PRIVATE_PROPACCESSOR)"
        UNSAFE_TYPE="$(DCC_UNSAFE_TYPE)"
        UNSAFE_CODE="$(DCC_UNSAFE_CODE)"
        UNSAFE_CAST="$(DCC_UNSAFE_CAST)"
        OPTION_TRUNCATED="$(DCC_OPTION_TRUNCATED)"
        WIDECHAR_REDUCED="$(DCC_WIDECHAR_REDUCED)"
        DUPLICATES_IGNORED="$(DCC_DUPLICATES_IGNORED)"
        UNIT_INIT_SEQ="$(DCC_UNIT_INIT_SEQ)"
        LOCAL_PINVOKE="$(DCC_LOCAL_PINVOKE)"
        MESSAGE_DIRECTIVE="$(DCC_MESSAGE_DIRECTIVE)"
        TYPEINFO_IMPLICITLY_ADDED="$(DCC_TYPEINFO_IMPLICITLY_ADDED)"
        XML_WHITESPACE_NOT_ALLOWED="$(DCC_XML_WHITESPACE_NOT_ALLOWED)"
        XML_UNKNOWN_ENTITY="$(DCC_XML_UNKNOWN_ENTITY)"
        XML_INVALID_NAME_START="$(DCC_XML_INVALID_NAME_START)"
        XML_INVALID_NAME="$(DCC_XML_INVALID_NAME)"
        XML_EXPECTED_CHARACTER="$(DCC_XML_EXPECTED_CHARACTER)"
        XML_CREF_NO_RESOLVE="$(DCC_XML_CREF_NO_RESOLVE)"
        XML_NO_PARM="$(DCC_XML_NO_PARM)"
        XML_NO_MATCHING_PARM="$(DCC_XML_NO_MATCHING_PARM)"
```

So to set the defines you could use the DCC_Define parameter like this:

```
msbuild yourproject.dproj /p:DCC_Define=MY_DEFINE
```

Others you will find in the .dproj file of your project

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

So it is Configuration and not Config. At least in Delphi 2007.

You might want to learn more about [msbuild in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to understand the scripts better and learn how you could make your own msbuild scripts to drive a build machine.

**Disclaimer:** This information is from a Delphi 2007 setup

Comment: Apparently it changed to config in 2009 or 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558147/delphi-msbuild-build-configurations-from-command-line