# Getting MSBuild to pass an arbitrary option to the compiler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, clang

What property or other option can I set, to tell MSBuild to pass an arbitrary option to the C++ compiler?

In cases where the compiler is known to MSBuild or the option has the same spelling as one used by a known compiler e.g. [How can I pass a parameter through MSBuild to the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063426/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-through-msbuild-to-the-compiler) the solution is to set a property corresponding to that specific option. However, in this case the compiler I'm using is clang and the option is unique to clang.

The closest likely candidate I could find in the documentation is CompilerResponseFile but when I set that (whether in the project file on the command line) nothing at all happens; maybe that's specific to C# not C++?

Is there another property I can use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `AdditionalOptions` metadata to the `ClCompile` items.  For example,

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>Your Options Go Here %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    <ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```