# How can I overwrite a setting in a Delphi 2007 dproj file with an empty string?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2007

[An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373991/what-are-the-msbuild-project-level-properties-for-delphi/2377796#2377796) describes how to override the command line compiler settings for Delphi 2007 by specifying them on the msbuild command line like this:

```
msbuild yourproject.dproj /p:DCC_DcpOutput="d:\bla\blub"
```

I have tested it and it works.

The Delphi IDE allows me to specify this path in the project options and if I leave it empty, it uses the default which suits me fine. Unfortunately I have some 3rd party packages that set this path to a subdirectory of the sources. Rather than editing the project settings, I would like to override this on the msbuild command line.

I tried this

```
msbuild yourproject.dproj /p:DCC_DcpOutput=""
```

and this

```
msbuild yourproject.dproj /p:DCC_DcpOutput=
```

but neither of them worked the way I want it. Both result in the .dcp file being generated in the directory where the .dproj file is located rather than the default output directory.

If I explicitly specify that directory like this

```
msbuild yourproject.dproj /p:DCC_DcpOutput=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Dcp
```

it works, but that means it will be specific to a particular Delphi installation, since this path is different depending on the Windows version (the above is Windows 8, in Windows XP the path is different).

Since I want to use this in a script that automatically compiles and installs all required packages for a project in a given Delphi 2007 installation, which can be on Windows XP, Windows 7 32 bits, Windows 7 64 bits and Windows 8 64 bits, I would like to avoid this.

I could try to use some environment variable, but none seems to fit the requirement.

So, is there any way to get the behaviour as if there was no DCC_DcpOutput entry in the .dproj file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify an empty value for the DCP output dir in the project options the IDE will take the value from the environment options. The default value for that is `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp` which can be checked within the IDE.

So specifying `%BDSCOMMONDIR%\Dcp` should do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps %BDSCOMMONDIR% might be a better choice then.

Comment: Do you run this from the command prompt and did you run rsvars.bat first?

Comment: I do indeed. So it is very odd that %BDSCOMMONDIR% doesn't work because it is definitely being set in rsvars.bat. I'll investigate.

Comment: I must have done something wrong when I tried it the first time. It works now. Maybe it was a simple typo. If you adapt your answer to say %BDSCOMMONDIR% instead of $(BDSCOMMONDIR), I'll accept it.

Comment: @dummzeuch did you run the RSVars batch file first?